# Selenium getSize function does not return correct rounded value

Tags: selenium

I am using selenium getSize function to get width and height of an element.
As I can see in inspect, width of element is "64.86px". 
However, the value returned by below line:

```
int width = webElement.getSize.getWidth();
```

is 64 px and not 65px. Similar issue for other elements as well because of which tests are failing.
Can anyone suggest a workaround for this?

Comment: Use a script injection to get the exact size: `var r=arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect(); return [r.width, r.height];`

Comment: On what element you are trying to get the width. in general there will be a chance that, the element may be surrounded with other elements and if you get the width for the surrounded element, then you may get the wrong value. Eg: An image may surrounded with a span tag or may placed in side table cell. So make sure to check the element on which you are applying the getSize() method. If you share your HTML code you may get better answer for your question.

Comment: When you see with the inspector, the "dimension" of the browser is the same of when you try with selenium?

Comment: @AuroSarma
I need the width of text written in button. this is html code:

<button class="Button" selected="false" type="button" id="button_instance">
<span>hello</span>
</button>

Comment: I am using below code to fetch text width:

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.XPath("//button[@id='button-instance']//span"));
int textWidth = element.getSize.getWidth();

Comment: your data is in span tag, and you don't need to use width property. follow the below steps and try.
1. get the xpath for span tag.
2. Use getText() method on in and store the return value in a string.
3. Use Java's string length method to get the length of your string.